# Changing the text of "mass-produced" labels

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Hy All,
I'm creating a layout for a database, and made a big canvas which are the lines, spawning smaller canvas inside them (as cells) to contain labels for the data. It looks nice, but the problem is, that due to this "mass-creation" of canvas and label widgets, none of them stays uniqly addressable, they are all named after the same variable when created in a for loop. Any idea how to tag/address them during the creation so I can edit them later?

```
for f in range(15)
z = z+1
f = Label(someFrame, width = 45 if  z < 4  else 12, text = f, borderwidth=2, relief="groove", bg = "#E5E5E5" if Color == True else "#B2B2B2" )
f.pack(side = LEFT)
```

It may look a bit messy, but you have a picture at least how the widgets are being created and what is my issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You're having a problem you shouldn't have. Use collection types such as dictionary or list.

Comment: Please format your code better using {} button.

Comment: Where should I use {}? I'm quite new in python, so will need some additional help to follow your advises.

Comment: It's a feature on site, has _nothing_ to do with Python. It is just a button that formats your code piece in [so]. Select the code you've pasted, then click on {} button or press Ctrl-K. I'm telling that because the code you've porvided has indentation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your widgets in a dictionary. Something like this:

```
widget_dict = {}
for idx in range(10):
    widget_dict['abc' + str(idx)] = label(root, ...)
```

Then you can access each widget through its dictionary key:

```
widget_dict[abc2].config(text='Banana')
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your for loop create a list. Then inside of the for loop just append every label to the list. Or you can use a dictionary to store them, depending on how you want to deal with that.

Comment: If I store all the instance IDs, how can I access them after that?

Comment: You need to store the instance itself. Like `foo_list.append(f)` in your for loop.

Comment: So i will have a list with entries like "Tkinter.Label instance at 0x14A9F9E0". But how can I call this instance later to edit it?

Comment: That is just how it prints the instance. You could call an attribute like `foo_list[0].text`

Comment: As these widgets are labels, I tried to call its text, but I got the error 
AttributeError: Label instance has no attribute 'text'

So now I know how to reach it, but can not get it's attributes.

Comment: This is Tkinter? The text can be changed like `foo_list[0]['text'] = 'something'`

Comment: The list idea was great, but I choose the foo_list[0].configure(text ="New Text") solution, as it looks more straight-forward. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sure, glad to help!